# How to remove Innerhtml extra span tags

Tags: web-part

I'm adding li item behind code but for no reason there is a span tag adding for each li item. Any hint will be appreciated. TIA.

```
      xx = "<li><a href='#slide" + ictr.ToString() + "'><img src='" +           curItem["BioImageUrl"].ToString() + "'></a></li>";
                        xx = xx.Replace("<span>", "");
                        xx = xx.Replace("</span>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that JavaScript could be adding the spans.

Are you using any extra frameworks? i.e. Telerik, jQuery etc...

I would remove everything except the essentials, check if this fixes it and slowly add back in everything until you see the spans again.

Failing that create a simple aspx page separately and see if you are getting the same results.